# Inequality involving slightly larger base and slightly smaller exponent

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, logarithms, exponentiation

I recently stumbled over a problem I am not able to solve. I want to show that

$$
(a+1-b)\cdot(a+1)^{b-1}\leq a^b,\quad a,b \in \mathbb{N}_{++}, a\geq b
$$

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28a%2B1-b%29*%28a%2B1%29%5E%28b-1%29%3C%3Da%5Eb) this seems to be true, however I am failing to prove this.

What I tried to do is to take the log and use some inequality on the log ($\log(x+1)\leq x$). However. this bound seems to be too wide. I get

$$
ab-b \leq b\log a
$$
but from there I'm not able to find an upper bound for $b\log a$ that satisfies the inequality.

Does someone have some hints on other inequalities to look into? (No homework, real problem). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\iff \frac{a+1-b}{a+1}\leq \left(\frac{a}{a+1} \right)^b\iff 1-\frac{b}{a+1}  \leq \left(1-\frac{1}{a+1}  \right)^b$$
Let's study the function $f(x)=(1-x)^b+bx-1$ for $b\in\mathbb{N}_{++}$ and $x>0$.

We have   $f'(x)=b(1-(1-x)^{b-1})\geq 0$  for $x>0$ and $b \geq 1$.

Then $f(x)$ is increasing function and $f(x) \geq f(0) = 0$. (Q.E.D)

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution

Comment: Hi @NN2, could you drop me an email at leonard.papenmeier@cs.lth.se if you like? We would like to acknowledge your help if you're interested.

Comment: @Leonard Thank you, but don' worry. If necessary (e.g. for a publication that requires this solution), you can delete the question and use the solution.

Comment: Thanks, we didn't end up using this proof, but we still wanted to ask :)

Comment: @Leonard You're welcome! :)